# Why is my BufferedReader not reading my file correctly?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have a small program that reads a number from a .txt file, increments it, and prints it back out to the file each time it is run:

```
public class ClientCounter {

    int count = 0;
    String input = "";

    public int addClient() {

        try (
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        ) {
            input = in.readLine();

            System.out.println("Input line is " + input);

            if (input != null)
                count = Integer.parseInt(input);

            System.out.println("Client count is: " + count);
            count++;

            System.out.println("After increment, count is: " + count);

            String output = Integer.toString(count);
            System.out.println("Output is " + output);

            out.println(output);

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("FNFE!");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOE!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return count;

    }
```

However, every time I try running it, I get this output:

```
Input line is null
Client count is: 0
After increment, count is: 1
Output is 1
```

My `test.txt` file is always left only containing a single number, `1`.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I think is because you read the file that you are writing. `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));` create a new file which is empty.

Comment: File might not be ready . when you are trying to read it . trying closing the writer

Comment: Try using a `RandomAccessFile` instead, and open it in read/write mode?

Comment: The mistake I can see in your program is You cannot open a same file for reading and writing at a same time, it is serial operation and you have close one to do another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every time you are rewriting new file.

try as below, second argument (true) indicates to uses existing file.

```
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt",true));
```

Above answer is wrong..updated answer below...

**Edited code**: May be **user270349** is correct. below code works for me.

public class ClientCounter {

```
static int count = 0;
static String input = "";

public static void main(String args[]){
    addClient();
}

public static int addClient() {

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        input = in.readLine();
        if (input != null)
            count = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println("Client count is: " + count);
        count++;
        in.close();

        System.out.println("After increment, count is: " + count);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
        String output = Integer.toString(count);
        System.out.println("Output is " + output);

        out.println(output);
        out.flush();out.close();

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FNFE!");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOE!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: after-edit: You should use try-finally or try-with-resources to close resources. With your code if something unexpected fails the file may remain open. For example `count = Integer.parseInt(input);` might fail if the line does not contain an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the files as soon as you are done with them. It is also bad idea to have the same file open two times.
Maybe you should do this:

```
BufferedReader in = ...
try {
  count = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
} finally {
  in.close();
}
count++;
  PrintWritter out = ...
try {
  out.println(count);
} finally {
  out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the file. Your modifications are lost when the program ends and the buffer hasn't been written to disk.

Comment: This might not be exact. Files are closed on JVM exit.

Comment: I've seen this happen to so many beginners. Close resources after using, or you'll get unpredictable (although in this case predictable) results.

Answer (score 0):

For reading something from file...

> ```
> File f = new File("test.txt");
> ```
>
> FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
>
> BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(fr);
>
> String str = null;
>
> while ((str = br.readLine())!=null) {
>
> // Line is stored in 'String s'. Do whatever you want with str
>
> }
>
> br.close(); //don't forget to close instance of BufferedReader by calling close method.

For writing something in the file...

```
File f = new File("newfile.txt");
String content = "This is something I want to write";
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(f);
bw.write(content);
bw.close();
```

Comment: You should use try-finally or try-with-resources to close resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class BufferedReaderTest {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
         int count = 0;
         String input;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\this.txt"));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("E:\\this.txt"));
            input = br.readLine();
            if (input != null)
                count = Integer.parseInt(input);
            System.out.println("Client count is: " + count);

            System.out.println("After increment, count is: " + (++count));

            String output = Integer.toString(count);
            System.out.println("Output is " + output);

            pw.println(output);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("FNFE!");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOE!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```